# Script thinks input is a command?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm just getting started on a script that does basic shell commands, but the second function, which is supposed to take a valid year and month and plug them into cal, is returning with this error:

```
Enter the year:
2014
/home/duncan/menuscript.sh: line 34: [2014: command not found
/home/duncan/menuscript.sh: line 34: [2014: command not found
This is an invalid year
```

This is the code I am working on, I have looked for the answer already, and I cant figure out why it wont compile.. I am not trying to enter the date as a command!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to Duncan's main menu"
function press_enter
{
    echo ""
    echo -n "Press Enter to continue"
    read
    clear
}
year=
month=
selection=
until [ "$selection" = "9" ] 
do
  clear
  echo ""
  echo "    1 -- Display users currently logged in"
  echo "    2 -- Display a calendar for a specific month and year"
  echo "    3 -- Display the current directory path"
  echo "    4 -- Change directory"
  echo "    5 -- Long listing of visible files in the current directory"
  echo "    6 -- Display current time and date and calendar"
  echo "    7 -- Start the vi editor"
  echo "    8 -- Email a file to a user"
  echo "    9 -- Quit"
  echo ""
  echo "Make your selection:"
  read selection
  echo ""
  case $selection in
    1) who ; press_enter ;;
    2) echo "Enter the year:" ;
       read year ;
       if [$year>1] || [$year<9999]; then
         echo "Enter the month:" 
         read month
         if [0<$month<12]; then
           cal -d $year-$month 
           press_enter
         else
           echo "This is an invalid month"
           press_enter
         fi
       else
          echo "This is an invalid year"
          press_enter 
       fi ;;

    9) exit ;;
    *) echo "Please enter a valid option" ; press_enter ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: without looking too close, since you're using `#!/bin/bash` anyway, why not use `select` rather than `case` here? It does pretty much all of that automatically, I think. Though, if I recall correctly - *(not guarantee)*, `bash` can sometimes trip up `*)` rather than `(*)`.... Oh yeah, the issue is probably here: `if [0<$month<12]` - you want some spaces and quotes I think...

Comment: Put a space between the [ and the following text. This ought to fix it

Comment: @mikeserv Spaces and quotes alone will not make it work.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - probably not.

Comment: @danielkullmann No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a (common) syntax error in this line (OK, not only one...):

```
[$year>1]
```

1. `[` is not a special character but an ordinary command. Thus the rest of the line is parameters and those must be separated by whitespace: `[ "$year" > 1 ]`
2. The next problem is that `>` is not an ordinary parameter but the redirection character (a metacharacter). Thus the shell sees (e.g.) `[2014` and looks for a command with this name. If there was one then the shell would write its output to the file `1]`...

If you use `[ ... ]` then you need the operator `-gt` (greater than):

```
[ "$year" -gt 1 ]
```

An alternative is to use the `bash` reserved word `[[` instead of `[`. You still have to use the whitespace as separator but you can omit the quotes:

```
[[ $year -gt 1 ]]
```

or you can use arithmetic expressions to compare integers:

```
((year > 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, right before you posted this I tried just adding the spaces, and it worked without the double brackets

Comment: @Duncan It is not working (the way you expect) if you keep using `>` and `<`. And `0<$month<12` is not working at all, not even with `[[`.

Comment: I split it up into $month>0 and $month<12 and it works smoothly. Also, you were right about [[ with only [ it gave the correct cal but with a small error above

Comment: @Duncan Then you may accept this answer so that the readers of this site see that your problem is solved.

Comment: @Duncan Note that you cannot use `>` inside double brackets either. Well, you can, syntactically speaking, but it doesn't do what you might think it does: it compares strings, not numbers, so e.g. `[[ 10 > 2 ]]` is false. You can use familiar arithmetic syntax inside double parentheses.